# sqlite3_bind_text SQLITE_STATIC vs SQLITE_TRANSIENT for c++ string

Tags: c++, sqlite

I have a method that returns a c++ std::string, and then I convert it to a c_str() before passing it into sqlite3_bind_text. My question is, should this be using SQLITE_STATIC or SQLITE_TRANSIENT?

```
sqlite3_bind_text(insertStatement, 0, suspect->GetIpString().c_str(), -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
// Do some stuff in same function then sqlite3_step
```

The documentation for sqlite3_bind_text says,

> The fifth argument to sqlite3_bind_blob(), sqlite3_bind_text(), and
>   sqlite3_bind_text16() is a destructor used to dispose of the BLOB or
>   string after SQLite has finished with it. The destructor is called to
>   dispose of the BLOB or string even if the call to sqlite3_bind_blob(),
>   sqlite3_bind_text(), or sqlite3_bind_text16() fails. If the fifth
>   argument is the special value SQLITE_STATIC, then SQLite assumes that
>   the information is in static, unmanaged space and does not need to be
>   freed. If the fifth argument has the value SQLITE_TRANSIENT, then
>   SQLite makes its own private copy of the data immediately, before the
>   sqlite3_bind_*() routine returns.

GetIpString returns an std::string, but will that string continue to exist after the call if I don't explicitly make a copy of it? Also, is it safe to use .c_str() without SQLITE_TRANSIANT in general? I know SQLITE_TRANSIENT would be the safe choice, but I want to avoid the copy/performance hit if it isn't needed since this query is going to get run a lot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your case, the string object returned by `GetIpString()` is likely to get destructed before the query gets executed and finalized, so you should `SQLITE_TRANSIENT`.

Generally, you should not bother about temporary copies unless you have actual performance problems that you have measured to be caused by this.

Comment: Not entirely, true, a blob can be very large, so memory wastage/fragmentation can also be an issue.